# Corona SDK crash when trying to combine filters/effects

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create new effect by combining existing ones and Corona Simulator crashes.

Here is my code

```
graphics.defineEffect({
    language = "glsl",
    category = "filter",
    name = "myEffect",
    graph = {
        gray = { effect = "filter.grayscale", input1 = "paint1" },
        --final = { effect = "filter.contrast", input1 = "gray" },
    },
    output = "gray"
});

local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
rect:setFillColor(1, 0, 0);
rect.fill.effect = "filter.myEffect";
```

Also question about arguments for filter. How can I specify arguments for filter contrast in this sample?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently bringing trouble to me too. I found it to be solvable by declaring the graph definitions of the effects in a nodes table.

I included the solution and corrected syntax below.

```
graphics.defineEffect({
    language = "glsl",
    category = "filter",
    name = "myEffect",
    graph = {
      nodes = {
         gray = { effect = "filter.grayscale", input1 = "paint1" }
         --final = { effect = "filter.contrast", input1 = "gray" },
      },
       output = "gray"
    }
})

local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
rect:setFillColor(1, 0, 0);
rect.fill.effect = "filter.myEffect";
```

Regarding the contrast questions, excuse me if I misunderstood but this should be a viable solution

```
graphics.defineEffect({
    language = "glsl",
    category = "filter",
    name = "myEffect",
    graph = {
      nodes = {
         gray = { effect = "filter.grayscale", input1 = "paint1" },
         final = { effect = "filter.contrast", input1 = "gray" }
      },
       output = "final"
    }
})

local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
rect:setFillColor(1, 0, 0);
rect.fill.effect = "filter.myEffect";
rect.fill.effect.final.contrast = 2
```

A good introduction to this is [Tutorial: Multi-Pass Shaders in Graphics 2.0 by Bryan Smith](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/17/tutorial-multi-pass-shaders-in-graphics-2-0/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried second code you wrote and it works, but shape is red instead of being gray.

Comment: This is intended. Try to change the contrast to 0 to see it without effect.

This answers your question of why it was crashing and how to change the contrast parameter in a noded filter. To get a desired effect you will have to play around with the implementation a bit. You could hit up another question now that you have it working so far.